# How to include multiple classes in a single library include?

Tags: c++

I'm making a library that consists of multiple classes.

Here are the files used:

```
mylib.cpp        
mylib_global.h   //Qt requirement for shared lib
mylib.h          //This is what i'd like to import 

oneclass.cpp     //The classes below provide the functionality  
oneclass.h
twoclass.cpp
twoclass.h
```

I would like to achieve the following:

```
#include "mylib.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  OneClass oneClass;
  TwoClass twoClass;
}
```

So, i'm just importing the `mylib.h` in some other application header and because of it the `OneClass` and `TwoClass` are available there.

Can this be achieved?
Also, please comment if this is a conceptually wrong way to implement libraries, and if so, why?

Comment: In addition to Matthias' answer, another way is to define those classes in mylib.h, and implement them in mylib.cpp with the help of scope resolution operator.

Comment: It is also good to place libraries in a namespace of its own, that way you avoid collisions with other libraries/headers

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that can be achieved.

Simply include all public definitions that your libraries provide into the libraries main header file.
In your example make mylib.h should look like as follows:

```
#include "oneclass.h"
#include "twoclass.h"
```